# Img file name as title & alt attribute from CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, w3c-validation

I want to know if we can write dynamically ALT & title attribute's value same as the img file name? I think it will possible by using css `content` property but dont know much about it.

like `<img src="file_name.jpg" alt="File Name" title="File Name">`

If it is possible then also I want both the attributes having the clean & formatted values like I dont want `_` underscore. may be it can be remove as well from CSS?

Comment: are you saying you want to change alt and title attributes using CSS ... and that you think you can change the src attribute using CSS?

Comment: @JaromandaX - I want to write the value of both the attribute same as the file_name without .jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img').attr({ //change multiple attributes
    title: $(this).attr('src').replace('_', '').replace('.jpg', ''), //to the src attr without _ and .jpg
    alt: $(this).attr('src').replace('_', '').replace('.jpg', '')
});
```

You can't use `content` because:

> CSS has a property called content. It can only be used with the pseudo
>   elements :after and :before. It is written like a pseudo selector
>   (with the colon), but it's called a pseudo element because it's not
>   actually selecting anything that exists on the page but adding
>   something new to the page.

This will put text in front or after an element, but does not change it's properties!

Comment: Yes, @thomas this is the answer I'm looking for, but can we do this with CSS `content` propoerty?